# Easy Photoshop action or other Adobe automation to generate stylised stacked images

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, actions

In my job I need to often showcase screens of our work. I find it's very stylish to showcase images like this one:

[Beautiful stack of screens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K2RMm.jpg)

[Resting iPad screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0wnOq.jpg)

Is there an easy way to do this in any Adobe software -- PS, or Fireworks, or Illustrator -- so that all I need to do is add images and all the rest is done automatically? I know actions are one kind of automation, but perhaps there are other tricks which I don't even know how to ask for. Basically I want to make this simple for "business users" to add images to via drag and drop, or file-open, and not tinker with the actual stylisation.

Welcome any thoughts, and ideally any pointers to these types of styles. Variations I can think of are showing images inside a large iMac or iPad kept next to each other.

Thank you.

Comment: Thank you. Isometric helps. So now I have the vocabulary right. However, my question is a bit more -- how should I automate the "3d explosion" but also the iPad lying down so that people just need to "drop in" images and the rest will be automatic?

Comment: One uses [Smart Objects](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/create-smart-objects.html) as layers take a look on how [these](http://graphicburger.com/down/?q=nexus-6-psd-mockup) templates are [done](http://graphicburger.com/isometric-perspective-mock-up/)

Comment: Thank you. If this was an answer, I'd pick it as the correct one.